# Moving list template to different farm with different site template

Tags: 2010, list, site-template, list-template

I have a simple list that I saved as a template, and moved to a different site collection in a different web application. The list template isn't showing up in the create new list dialog, and I've figured out, it must be, because the source site template is different from the destination.

Is there anyway around this restriction?

Comment: Was the list template created with the same language/locale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the source site collection's base language is different from the destination site collection's base language then the issue mentioned by you happens. To fix, the list template has XML files which has language code present inside which needs to be  updated to the destiantion language code and create the cab/template.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to cab it, extract the xml and change the language code to the destination, and reupload, now it works. Thanks!